# Meaning and usage of だっており: 「見た目にも秩序だっており、...」

Tags: verbs

> 日本での並び方は、先に来た人から順番に一列に並び、空いたカウンターに、列の一番前の人が向かいます。見た目にも秩序**だっており**、列が一列しかないので、割り込みも容易ではありません。このような並び方を、フォーク並びといいます。

This だっており confuses me a lot, because I cannot figure out its meaning and usage after consulting the dictionary and searching online sentences.

Is this だっており composed of だ(断定助動詞)＋って(quotative particle)＋おり(alternative of いる)?
Or だって+ おり(alternative of いる)? In either way the meaning doesn't make sense to me.

Meaning of だって listed in the dictionary:

> (1)ある特別と思われる場合をあげて、それも他と同様であるということを表す。
> 「さる―木から落ちるさ」
> (2)いくつかの物事を代表として例示し、他もそれと同様であるということを表す。
> 「君―、ぼく―、みんな仲間だ」
> (3)不定称の指示語に付き、肯定／否定の語と呼応して、全面的な肯定／否定を表す。
> 「だれ―、行ける所だ」「だれ―死にたくない」

Answer (score 3):

This 秩序だっており is the te-form of an intransitive verb [秩序【ちつじょ】立【だ】つ](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%A7%A9%E5%BA%8F%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4), followed by a subsidiary verb おる in its continuative form. The dictionary entry you have cited is not relevant. Similar compound verbs include 目立つ, 際立つ, 巣立つ, 役立つ, 毛羽立つ, 殺気立つ and 規則立つ.