# Use of ており JLPT N3: 「このような都市はコンパクトシティと言われており、...」

Tags: grammar, jlpt, subsidiary-verbs, renyōkei

I am studying a reading book for JLPT3 and I came across a grammar I can't seem to find:

> このような都市はコンパクトシティと**言われており**、お年寄りも気軽にいろいろな場所へ行くことができる。

Can someone explain the use of the verb おる here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14703/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59037/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3334/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an irregular [中止法](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/5010) usage of いる you have to remember. Although the masu-stem of いる is い, you cannot say this:

> ❌ このような都市はコンパクトシティと言われて**い**、お年寄りも気軽にいろいろな場所へ行くことができる。

Instead, you **must** say this:

> ✅ このような都市はコンパクトシティと言われて**おり**、お年寄りも気軽にいろいろな場所へ行くことができる。

This type of ており used in the middle of a sentence has no honorific or humble meaning. For more details, see [my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/94594/5010).

Longer ichidan verbs (e.g. 老いる) do not have this irregularity, so you can safely say something like "私は老い、いずれ死ぬだろう".

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry you had to repeat the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

That's one of the multiple "keigo" things (i.e. "being polite, pushing yourself down" hierarchy etc.)

I guess おる is most commonly (just if hypothetically counting) used to start emails in "...いつもお世話になっております" (instead of just "お世話になっています")

A bit like, when ending the mails. よろしくお願いします vs 宜しくお願い致します

Comment: You're saying the sentence is written keigo?

Comment: ^ 主語が自分じゃないので謙譲語(humble form)でもないし、文末が「できます。」じゃなくて「できる。」だから丁寧語(polite form)でもなさそうですよね。[この回答](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14703/9831)にあるように、formal form なのでは